# Error handling on controller SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, runtime-error

I am developing an application in jax-rs and spring mvc.
I want to notify my client each time when an default error is occured like
400, 403, 404, 405 and 415.

### Controller

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/customer")
    public class CustomerController {

        @Autowired
        CustomerService customerService;

        // ........xxxxxx..............xxxxxxx................xxxxxxx.............//


            @CrossOrigin
            @RequestMapping(value = "/", 
                            method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public @ResponseBody String fetchCustomer() throws JsonProcessingException {
                return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(customerService.fetchAllCustomer());
            }

            // ........xxxxxx..............xxxxxxx................xxxxxxx.............//

}
```

### Client

```
$http({
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: baseUrl + '/customer'
      }).success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        // you can also use
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response);
      }).error(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

When i request a service from client i want to send response back with status code and custom message.

### Example

When i defind method = post on controller and from client i send request as get service should return message like

```
error:{
     Status Code: 405,
     Message:  Invalid Method 
     url: error/405
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#errors-and-rest) out for reference.

Define a method for handling the specific error scenario and annotate it as `@ExceptionHandler`. The exception in your scenario (request method not supported) is `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class`. You can create more generic handler methods using `Throwable, Exception` etc.

In order to prevent duplication of error handling across controllers, one convenient way is to define all handlers in single class and use `@ControllerAdvice` on that. This way, all handlers will be applied to all controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Do not return a String but return a org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.
You can add status codes to this object

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("This is a response", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
return responseEntity;
```

So your method signature will also change as below

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> fetchCustomer() throws JsonProcessingException {
        try {
            String str = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(customerService.fetchAllCustomer());
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(str, HttpStatus.OK);
         }
        catch (Exception e) {
             return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

If there is an error, you can either use controller advice or catch the exception and update the ResponseEntity appropriately